# InnoDB or MyISAM - What's the "correct" database storage engine for EE4/EE5?

Tags: database, ee4, ee5

As I am looking into my database via phpMyAdmin I see that most of the tables are MyISAM, some are InnoDB (e.g. from plugins). As far as I read in the web InnoDB is known as "better", but I am no expert.

As I have been upgrading EE for years I am not sure if it's problematic if MyISAM is used instead of InnoDB. Also I would like to know if it could cause problems with EE to convert all tables to InnoDB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE now defaults to using InnoDB type tables in MySQL.

The docs have instructions on how one can convert MyISAM tables to InnoDB ([here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/converting-to-innodb.html)).

Whether it makes any difference on an average site is moot, and there should be no issues if you run a site with a mixture of MyISAM and InnoDB tables.

HTH.

Comment: This is absolutely helpful, thanks!